# If...were to, would/Present Simple Tense?

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

> *If her dream of being naked in front of Simon **were to** come true – and she knew, somehow, that it would – she **needed** to be the
> sveltest version of herself that had ever existed. Fries wouldn't help
> peel away those pounds.*

2010, M. S. Simpson, Kabuki in a G-String, page 158

Hello, everyone! It's an honor to be here!

This is an example sentence from Wiktionary.

I think that instead of "*If her dream [...] **were to*** come true-[...]", should be "*If her dream [...] **was to*** come true-[...]".

Or it depends on dialect?

Thanks!

Comment: It's nothing to do with Past tense - it's a *hypothetical future* in your exact context, regardless of whether we use explicitly Subjunctive *If it **were** [to happen]* or relaxed / informal *If it **was** [to happen]*. In many similar contexts the Subjunctive references a "timeless" unreal situation, so Past and Future aren't really relevant anyway. English has always tended to use a limited number of different verb inflections, and the trend here is to abandon "literary" ***were*** in favour of ***was*** unless the context is particularly formal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the main clause" *(if it **were*** OR *she **knew*** OR *she **needed**)*. But whatever *you* think, I'm gonna suggest that the main *verb* should be ***she knew***. That makes the entire utterance a statement about the past (where it's irrelevant that *within* that past is a Subjunctive reference to a possible future). If you change ***she knew*** to ***she knows***, you *must* reflect that with ***she needs*** and ***that has ever existed***, so it's crucial. But you can just change ***needed*** to ***would need*** with no other changes (so it's *not* crucial).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand that, but what I don't understand is why the writer used Past Simple Tense in the main clause!? He wrote, _"She needed to be[...]"_, but it should be _"She would need to be [...]"_, am I right?

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's not what I mean! There is a certain grammatical rule.  If I want to state something about a _hypothetical future_, it needs to be like this: _"If her dream [...] were to come true [..] –she **would** **need** to be the sveltest version of herself [...]"_. But in the original sentence, we read:  _"If her dream [...] were to come true [..] –she **needed** to be the sveltest version of herself [...]"_.  So, the original sentence doesn't follow this rule, am I right?

Comment: No, you're mistaken. As I said in previous comment, *you can just change **needed** to **would need** with no other changes.* Consider *If you want to catch the 7 o'clock train **you need** to leave in five minutes.* It makes absolutely no difference if we change that to ***you will need*** (or more naturally, ***you'll need***). And note that we can cast all that into "deferential backshifted" Past *If you **wanted** to catch the 7 o'clock train **you would need / you'd need** to leave in five minutes.*